# Jetty Error: No plugin found for prefix 'jetty'

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, maven-plugin, maven-jetty-plugin

I make [this](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/hello-world) tutorial from cloud.google,

there i should use

[image]

but the command prompt says:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Desktop-PC.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

I downloaded Jetty [here](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/) and put in in the maven plugin folder in
".m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins" and I also downloaded the
eclipse plugin.

***My Question is:***

How to install and start maven-jetty-plugin in the cmd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My faults are, that I don´t navigate to
the `pom.xml` from the project in the `CLI`
and I have to add this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.13.v20161014</version>
</plugin>
```

Into the Projects `pom.xml`.